# Call class method from function running in other process in Python

Tags: python, ipc, python-multiprocessing

I have a main GUI to receive data from an amplifier and plot it. When I click a button, a new process is created and it is receiving data with a blocking method (that is why I need another process). My question is, how can I send the received data to the main GUI to plot it? Here is an scheme and what I've tried:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# Load the .ui file
gui_main_class = uic.loadUiType("gui_main.ui")[0]

# Function that receive the data (RUNS IN OTHER PROCESS)
def manager_process(gui_main):
    amp = AmpReceiver()
    while True
        data = amp.getData()
        **HERE IS WHERE I HAVE TO CALL draw_data(data) IN GuiMainClass TO PLOT THE DATA**


# Main class that instantiates the UI
class GuiMainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gui_main_class):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.receive_data_process)

    def receive_data_process(self):
        self.data_receiver_process = mp.Process(target=manager_process)
        self.data_receiver_process.start()

    def draw_data(self, data):
        CODE TO UPDATE THE PLOT (NOT INTERESTING FOR THE QUESTION)


# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = GuiMainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think that it has to be possible, but I don't know how to adress the problem because I found that passing an object between processes actually copies the object but don't pass it in reference (so you can't call the methods on the original one) So, what do you think is the best option? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could run the other process within a QThread and emit the recieved data to QT's main thread. Keep in mind just the main thread is allowed to access QT's widgets.

Comment: And what is the difference between a Qthread and a Process? I use a process because I want to take advantage of a multicore processor, It can be possible with a QThread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `multiprocessing` module offers [several techniques for IPC](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#exchanging-objects-between-processes). The easiest one for your situation is probably a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Queue): when `manager_process` retrieves data it puts it on a shared `Queue` instance. In the original process you run a separate thread that retrieves items from the queue and calls `draw_data`.

Comment: I've been reading the Queue class documentation and I think I will try that, thank you! When I come to a solution I will update the question

Comment: Queue class and a Thread listening with queue.get() blocking method solved my problem. Thank you very much!